# Unable to display dataset on WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, dataset

My problem is that I am unable to view the DataSet on my client side windows form. I am using the SetDataBinding method but I get an error saying that:

**Error**: `"Systems.Windows.Forms.DataGridView" doesn't contain any defination for SetDataBinding and no extension method accepting first type of argument"`

Here is web service code that returns Dataset:

```
  public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet getdata(String rollno)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123"))
            {
                string select = "select * from checkrecord where rollno=@rollno";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, myConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "students");
                return (ds);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;                
        }

    }
```

The client side code that binds the data:

```
      using System.Drawing;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Windows.Forms;
      using System.Web.Services;
      using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
      using WindowsFormsApplication1.dataset1;

     //dataset1 is my web reference name
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      { 
          public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }
          private void calldatagrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             Service1 MyService = new Service1();
            // Call the GetData method in the Web Service
            DataSet ds = MyService.getdata("abc");
            // Bind the DataSet to the Grid
            datagrid.SetDataBinding=ds;
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C#.NET".

Comment: sorry for the mistake will remember it in future ..thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change **datagrid.SetDataBinding=ds;** line to  **datagrid.DataSource=ds.Table[0];**
use below piece of code:

```
 Service1 MyService = new Service1();
 // Call the GetData method in the Web Service
  DataSet ds = MyService.getdata("abc");
 // Bind the DataSet to the Grid
  datagrid.DataSource=ds.Table[0];
```

another change:

in your webservice change   **"select * from checkrecord where *rollno=@rollno*";** this line to  **"select * from checkrecord where *rollno=\'"+rollno+"\'*";**

Comment: Yes I tried that, I got this error: "Systems.Data.DataSet" doesn't contain any defination for Table and no extension method accepting first type of argument"

Comment: ok..then put break point on DataSet ds = MyService.getdata("abc"); line and check that Are you getting table or not? if not then it means your webservice is not returing any table inside dataset..that means your query have no output..Run this query in sql and see what output is giving it.

Comment: @Parth_90 :I think I found the problem.. check my answer. I have edited.

Comment: I saw the edit both for the SQL query...I made the required , inserted breakpoint again at the line you mentioned ..it says ds contains null :-(

Comment: can you check that a query that you have mention what output giving in sql?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c join this chat room.. I am here r8 now..so we can directly clear your problem

Answer (score 2):

SetDataBinding is defined on DataGrid, not DataGridView (unrelated), and is a method not a property, and required two parameters. Try instead:

```
datagrid.DataSource = ds;
```

And optionally:

```
datagrid.DataMember = "TableName";
```

As an aside... Data-sets are a horrible horrible choice for web-services.

Comment: I tried that , my error disappeared and I got the windows form displayed with my DataGridView and a Command Button but when I clicked the Button I couldn't see the data on the GridView

Comment: @parth did you set the DataMember? Actually, settin the DataSource to the **table** may be easier, too

Comment: +1 for `Data-sets are a horrible horrible choice for web-services`

Comment: @MarcGravell : I tried adding the DataMember also. Still not able to see the dataset on my DataGridView. Any other better way to do it?

Comment: The better way is to not return a DataSet. Instead, return collections of POCO classes (Data Transfer Objects).